# Plotting Multiple Layers in R

Tags: r, plot, geospatial, spatial

I am attempting to plot multiple spatial layers onto one map. I cannot seam to get my points onto the US map. I am using    ggplot to map these spatial data. having trouble with the command add = TRUE to add points(coords) onto the "midwst" map. I am able to plot the two separately but could use some help getting coords on top of the midwst map. I feel like I might not be using the correct package commands with one another, but can't tell.

```
setwd("D:")

midwst <- readOGR(dsn="/ne_50m_states", layer="us")
fsites = read.csv(file = "/WHAT Baseflow//final_sites.csv", header=T, 
sep=",")

#Identify pts and Change projection

coords <- SpatialPoints(fsites[,c("Longitude", "Latitude")])

projection(coords) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2163")
spTransform(coords,CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 
+towgs84=0,0,0"))

#Extract States from US Map
plot(midwst, axes = T)
plot(coords, pch = 21, bg = "red", cex = .5, axes = T)
```

Comment: Its possible your transform has gone wrong and the points arent in the right place. What does `bbox(coords)` say?  If you `plot(coords)` and then add some axes for reference (`axis(1);axis(2)`), do the numbers look right? Are the Longitude and Latitude columns of `fsites` really in EPSG:2163?

Comment: What's `ggplot` got to do with it? I don't see you using it here.

Comment: Did you mean to do `"add=TRUE"` in the second plot function call? You say `add=TRUE` in your text but your code has `axes=T` and no `add` parameter. Something isn't right...

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of plotting multiple layers using R base methods

```
# Import "raster" package
library(raster)
# Get "Vietnam" from online database called GADM
HN<-getData(name = "GADM",country="Vietnam",level=0)

# Plotting HN map
par(mar=rep(2,4))
plot(HN,border="black",axes=T)

# Create some sample coordinates

df<-data.frame(x=seq(105,106,by=0.5),y=seq(20,21,by=0.5))

library(sp)
# Building a spatial point object
coordinates(df)<-~x+y

proj4string(df)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# Overlaying the spatial point object on Vietnam map
plot(df,add=T,col=2)
```

Comment: Yes, I did this ^ but whenever I add the add=T command to the points, they do not plot. When I remove the add=T then I am able to see the points in space

Comment: The problem is deeper than this, and is likely to be a coordinate transform problem, putting one set of data in the wrong place. See my comment.

Comment: If you don't provide dataset, I think that It is difficult for me. Why did you click "not useful" button?

Comment: you can add `par(mar=rep(2,4))` before plotting any graphs

Comment: @Tuyen If a user doesn't supply a dataset then the right thing to do is to add a comment asking for more info. I'm actually a bit confused by the question now, because it mentions "add=TRUE" in the text but not in the code. Again, a comment for clarification is the right thing to do.

Comment: @Spacedman I am confused too, but I am trying to add code and hping that it will help him. But he made me disappointed :)